# how to alternate rows based on odd/even index

Tags: reactjs

I want to loop over data and show it in a bootstrap grid with an image on the left, text on right, then for the next iteration show the text on the left and image on the right etc. However, when using `.map`, I can only put the odd/even condition inside the column when I actually need it before.

```
      <Row className="align-items-center">
        {data.map((d, index) => (
          <Col md={6}>
            {index % 2 ? (
              <Image
                src={d.img}
                width={500}
                height={500}
              />
            ) : (
              <p>{d.title}</p>
            )}
          </Col>
        ))}
       </Row>
```

So, I guess it should look something like this if done manually

```
<Row>
    <Col md={6}>
        Image
    </Col>
    <Col md={6}>
        Text
    </Col>
    <Col md={6}>
        Text
    </Col>
    <Col md={6}>
        Image
    </Col>
</Row>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are displaying either of `<Image>` or `<p>` depending on the `index`. You should  display both of them with their orders changed depending on the `index`

```
<Row className="align-items-center">
  {data.map((d, index) => (
      index % 2 ? (
        <>
          <Col md={6}>
            <Image
              src={d.img}
              width={500}
              height={500}
            />
          </Col>
          <Col md={6}>
            <p>{d.title}</p>
          </Col>
        </>
        ) : (
        <> 
          <Col md={6}>
            <p>{d.title}</p>
          </Col>
          <Col md={6}>
            <Image
              src={d.img}
              width={500}
              height={500}
            />
          </Col>
        </>
      ) 
  ))}
</Row>
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I had actually tried it like this already but it doesn't allow me to put `{index % 2` straight after the `data.map`. Error: error: Expression expected. error: Expected ',', got '}'

Comment: My bad. Edited the answer. Removed `{}` around condition checking. Can you try now?

Comment: Ah, yeah! That works :)